# permutations rolling die 6 times

Tags: probability, permutations, dice

How would you calculate the probability that if you roll a six sided die six times you will roll 1,2,3,4,5,6 consecutively.  I am totally lost on how to even calculate this.

Comment: It's just 1/6^6

Answer (score 5):

How many possible sequences of $6$ rolls of a six-sided die are there? How many of those sequences meet the desired criterion?

Now, how is the probability of an event defined, in general? For example, if you are choosing a shirt from your closet in the pitch dark, and you have $5$ black shirts out of a total of $18$ shirts, then what is the probability that the shirt you pick is black?

---

Another approach: $\frac16$ of the time, the first roll should be $1.$ $\frac16$ of that time, the second roll should be $2$. $\frac16$ of that time, the third roll should be $3,$ and so on. Hence, $\frac16$ of $\frac16$ of $\frac16$ of $\frac16$ of $\frac16$ of $\frac16$ of the time, the sequence of rolls should be $1,2,3,4,5,6.$ How can we express the number "$\frac16$ of $\frac16$ of ..." more simply?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to enlighten me?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter you addressed, but I think it'd be much more helpful if you'd at least include the notion of division or proportion in your answer ($A/B$, not, say, $b-a$), and preferably also the notion of multiplying to find the probability of independent events.

Comment: @msh210: Fair point. I don't want to give too much away, but I have tried to lead the OP a little closer to the desired notion.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of obtaining, specifically and in this order: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ is the same probability of obtaining any particularly specified sequence.

There are $6$ possible numbers for filling each position. And the probability of obtaining any particular specified number in one particular position is $\dfrac 16$. There are six rolls, therefor six different positions in the sequence. So we have a probability of $$\underbrace{\dfrac 16 \cdot \frac 16 \cdot \cdots \dfrac 16}_{6\;\text{ factors}} = \left(\dfrac 16\right)^6$$

Comment: Two clear answers and still closed +1